# Set image source - From different URL's

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

## Problem

I have a JS file that handles some background animations and canvas thingy's. Works perfectly - but for this little error, concerning setting an image source, I've found:

So the homepage of the site *http://localhost:XXXX/* is located here however the "real" URL is of course *http://localhost:XXXXX/Home/Index*.

So when a redirect sends me to the "full" url instead of the initial routed one. The javascript does not find the source.

## Current Solution

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute('href', window.location.href);

Logo = new Image();
Logo.src = "https://" + link.hostname + ":" + link.port + "/images/logo.png";
dotaLogo.addEventListener('load', initCanvas, false);
```

***This part is working in development environment for now.***

## Questions:

1. Is this way acceptable?
2. Obviously this is a Dev environment - will that `.port` part of the link fail in realtime?

Cheers for suggestions.

Comment: Have you checked this in `IE` browser? Particularly in `Edge`? I hope you will run into some issue, Meanwhile you can also use the `window.location` to extract the `hostname`, `port` etc.. same as `..createElement`

Comment: Good suggestion if I do opt for staying with this method. Thoughts on using a FileResult instead? Probably will have the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

you can just reference urls relatively by using `<img src="/images/blah.jpg">`

this will request `<protocol>://<hostname>:<port>/whatever`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Remember I have one javascript file that makes this call from two URL's. So this works only in one case if you re-read the question. http://localhost:xxxx/images/blag.jpg works fine. But when the url becomes full http://localhost:xxxx/Home/Index/Images. We got a problem. Also note I am doing this in javascript. There is no img element in the html since I  am using it in a canvas._

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be for each scenario? Sorry for explaining in HTML, setting the src attribute will work the same way